# How to get yarn to respect the "engines" requirement in package.json

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, yarnpkg

I'm trying to `yarn add` a package to the project, but I get an error about the resolved package being incompatible with my node version:

```
$ yarn add array-move --mode=skip-build
yarn add v1.22.18
[1/5] Validating package.json...
[2/5] Resolving packages...
[3/5] Fetching packages...
error array-move@4.0.0: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "^12.20.0 || ^14.13.1 || >=16.0.0". Got "10.24.1"
error Found incompatible module.
```

My `package.json` specifies a node engine:

```
"engines": {
  "node": "10.x"
},
```

Is there any way to `yarn add` a package and have yarn automatically choose a version that is compatible with my node version? Or do I need to manually find a version of that package that supports my node version and `yarn add` that version manually?

On a related note, what about recursive dependences? If I `yarn add some-package` that has a dependency like `"other-package": "^0.1.30"`, but version `"0.1.72"` is the last version of that other package that works with my node version, can I place additional version restrictions on that subpackage when yarn tries to resolve that dependency as well?

Comment: I'm sure you're aware but node.js 10 is almost a [year past EOL](https://endoflife.date/nodejs) (in fact node.js *12* is almost EOL) and you are probably going to experience increasing friction with installing new dependencies...